# (Vanila JS DOM) Why delete button isn't applied for all 'delete' classes..?

Tags: javascript, dom, crud

I am trying my first vanilla JS CRUD DOM manipulation project.
I have completed the add item function however delete function isn't working properly.
There are multiple delete buttons on HTML code, and I want it to be deleted when the button clicked. However, it is only working for the first item from the list. If I click the second or third delete button, it is just not working at all.

```js
document.querySelector('li').addEventListener('click', deleteOrTick);
//deleteTick
function deleteOrTick(e) {
  console.log("check click")
  if (e.target.className == 'delete') {
    console.log("delete clicked")
  }
  deleteTask(e);
  // delete task
  function deleteTask(e) {
    let remove = e.target.parentNode;
    let parentNode = remove.parentNode;
    parentNode.removeChild(remove);
  }
}
deleteOrTick();
```

```html
<ul class="card-list row m-2 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" id="card">
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">おはよう</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The snippet I made you gives a clue when run

Comment: `querySelector()` returns *the first* element matching the selector; if you want *all elements* matching the selector, you should use `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @yunzen, sorry but I do not understand what you are talking about; I did not compare alternatives, I just pointed out that the method the OP was using returns a single HTML element and mentioned the "equivalent" method which returns a list of HTML elements. Are you sure you are referring to my comment?

Comment: @secan Sorry! Those comments should have gone under mplungjan's answer

Comment: :)) no reason to be sorry, @yunzen; it can happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelector returns the first of the selected elements.

Also do not have one function inside the other

Lastly why call the delete when you load?

I think you meant to delegate

```js
document.getElementById('card').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const parent = tgt.closest('li');
  if (tgt.classList.contains('delete')) parent.remove();
  else if (tgt.classList.contains('update')) console.log("Update clicked for ",parent.querySelector(".card-title").textContent)
})
```

```html
<ul class="card-list row m-2 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" id="card">
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info update">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">おはよう</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info update">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info update">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Delegation is good. But I always try to delegate to the highest possible element in the DOM

Comment: @yunzen - why? I always try to delegate to the NEAREST possible element

Comment: @yunzen Compare the complexity between my code and yours. What are the benefits of your code over my much more readable code?

Comment: Look at my answer for a possible explanation

Comment: There is no better or worse of these two alternatives. Your approach is the one that has a higher degree of encapsulation, though

Comment: Your comments on your code are the same I would make, except I get as close as I can to the collection of elements. In this case obviously the UL. If more ULs one would zoom the eventhandler out

Answer (score 1):

Because `querySelector()` returns only the first match:

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

`window.getElementsByTagName()` could be more appropriate for your case

Comment: Delegating from the container is more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend doing it like this.

1. Add some semantic to your HTML code. In this case add the classNames `translation-card-list`, `translation-card`, etc
2. Make use of event bubbling by delegating the event listening to the `document` element and working with the `target` property of the event argument. This way you have only one Listener improving performance and by delegating you can add buttons at run time without adding new `EventListeners` in a complicated manner
3. Use the `closest` method of the `Event`'s `target` to use the semantic I added in section 1

```js
;(function(d) {
  const classNameCard = 'translations-card';
  const classNameUpdateButton = 'translations-card-update-button';
  const classNameDeleteButton = 'translations-card-delete-button';
  
  const onClick = function(e) {
    const target = e.target
    if (!target.closest(`.${classNameCard}`)) {
      return false
    }
    if (target.closest(`.${classNameUpdateButton}`)) {
      updateAction(e);
    } else if (target.closest(`.${classNameDeleteButton}`)) {
      deleteAction(e);
    }
  }
  
  const updateAction = function(e) {
    console.log('update')
  }
  const deleteAction = function(e) {
    const card = e.target.closest(`.${classNameCard}`);
    const cardList = card.parentNode;
    cardList.removeChild(card);
  }
  
  d.addEventListener('click', onClick)
  
}(document));
```

```html
<ul class="translations-card-list card-list row m-2 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center" id="card">
  <li class="translations-card card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-update-button btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-delete-button btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="translations-card card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">おはよう</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Good morning</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-update-button btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-delete-button btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
  <li class="translations-card card border-success m-3" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h2 class="card-title">にほんご</h2>
      <p class="card-text">Japanese</p>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-update-button btn btn-outline-info">update</button>
    <button type="button" class="translations-card-delete-button btn btn-outline-danger delete">delete</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```